# set canvas child in windows store application

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

i have created two canvas in xaml like this :

```
<Grid>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas2"    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="11" Grid.RowSpan="8" Background="White"  >
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" RightTapped="canvas1_RightTapped"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="11" Grid.RowSpan="8" Background="Transparent"  >
</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

now i want to make these canvases children of another canvas that should be create on button click . I am doing it like this :

```
Canvas canvas1d = new Canvas();
canvas1d.Height = canvas1.ActualHeight; 
canvas1d.Width = canvas1.ActualWidth; 
canvas1d = canvas1;
Canvas canvas2d = new Canvas();
canvas2d.Height = canvas1.ActualHeight;
canvas2d.Width = canvas1.ActualWidth;
canvas2d = canvas2;
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Height = canvas1.ActualHeight; 
canvas.Width = canvas1.ActualWidth;
canvas.Children.Add(canvas2d);
canvas.Children.Add(canvas1d);
```

but it is given an error

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.Element is already the child of another element
```

please help and correct this  code.

Comment: Why do you do `canvas1d = canvas1;` and `canvas2d = canvas2;`? You create 2 new `Canvas` and then completely ignore them by overwriting variables with already existing elements

Comment: actually i want to set canvas1 and canvas2 as children of canvas : 
`Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Height = canvas1.ActualHeight; 
canvas.Width = canvas1.ActualWidth;
canvas.Children.Add(canvas2);
canvas.Children.Add(canvas1);`
but it is given the same  error:
`An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.Element is already the child of another element`

Comment: Where are you declaring `canvas1` and `canvas2`? Did you mean to switch them around? I.e. `canvas1 = canvas1d;`?